# Anything Wrong with (char[32]){0} in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c, visual-studio, ffmpeg

===== background ====

This problem originates from using fFmpeg lib sample muxing.c in visual studio 2012, I found the the error:

```
error C2143: Syntax error missing ) before {
```

at

```
printf("pts:%s pts_time:%s dts:%s dts_time:%s duration:%s duration_time:%s stream_index:%d\n",
    av_ts2str(pkt->pts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->pts, time_base),
    av_ts2str(pkt->dts), av_ts2timestr(pkt->dts, time_base),
    av_ts2str(pkt->duration), av_ts2timestr(pkt->duration, time_base),
    pkt->stream_index);
```

and I found

```
#define AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE 32
#define av_ts2str(ts) av_ts_make_string((char[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE]){0}, ts)
```

for eliminate irrelevant statement, I just replace the big printf with

```
printf("pts:%s \n",
    (char[32]){0}
    );
```

but the error still the same, looks the error is from

```
(char[32]){0}
```

===== question ====

As this sample source file muxing.c is official one (I think), might not possibly wrong, so is the statement wrong or not compatible with VS compiler ? or I am missing something here ?

Comment: [This blog](http://blogs.gnome.org/rbultje/2012/09/27/microsoft-visual-studio-support-in-ffmpeg-and-libav/) and [ffmpeg docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html) suggest that it relies on C99 support.  Visual Studio supports C89 only.  You can either compile on Windows using gcc (which may be a hassle to setup) or follow the links above to a conversion tool that modifies the ffmpeg source to be C89 compliant

Comment: `(char[32]){0}` is a compound literal. It's a feature of C99. Microsoft's "C" compilers do not support C99, which is a shame. Try using the MinGW port of GCC to compile your code.

Comment: Compound literals are supported in VS2013.

Comment: @tab I tried with visual 2013 but no luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from what dasblinkenlight says, there is a way to compile ffmpeg (and maybe other source code using this and other C99 constructs) with MSVC. A script can convert this C99 code to hopefully equivalent C89 code automagically.

See [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b-or-Intel-C_002b_002b-Compiler-for-Windows) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The construct that looks like a cast of curly braces block to an array is called a *Compound Literal*. This is one of C99 features that have not been implemented in Visual Studio line of compilers.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to fix this problem, because a compound literal creates a temporary anonymous array that gets deallocated automatically. Hence, your nice short `printf` would be converted to something like this:

```
char buf1[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = {0};
av_ts_make_string(buf1, pkt->pts);
char buf2[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = {0};
av_ts_make_string(buf1, pkt->dts);
char buf3[AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE] = {0};
av_ts_make_string(buf1, pkt->duration);

printf("pts:%s pts_time:%s dts:%s dts_time:%s duration:%s duration_time:%s stream_index:%d\n",
    buf1, av_ts2timestr(pkt->pts, time_base),
    buf2, av_ts2timestr(pkt->dts, time_base),
    buf3, av_ts2timestr(pkt->duration, time_base),
    pkt->stream_index);
```